# how to remove html auto fill username & password?

Tags: html

Login form username and passwords are auto filled when i goes to login page.

I do not want to be filled automatically. User only should fill the form manually.

To solve this problem I have used

```
autocomplete='off'
```

but still I am getting same issue

Answer (score -2, accepted):

try making the inputs empty after page load

```
document.getElementById('userName').value = '';
```